# Status report on progress of a sequence of merges

Tags: t-sql, error-handling, transactions, merge

I want to use T-SQL to perform a sequence of merges.  I understand that if one fails, it rolls back, but I would like to print a message to the effect - so I know I need to go and check it.  I can't seem to find any examples of this to start with.  My first thought was to put the the transaction in a try, but then I'm not sure what happens with the rollback statement ... it seems weird putting that in the catch.  I'm sure others must have had wanted to do this previously.  Does anyone have an example of this?

NOTE:  I need to use the MERGE command.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code. [Try Catch help from msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx)

```
BEGIN TRY
    -- Table does not exist; object name resolution
    -- error not caught.
     SELECT * FROM Table;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
      Print ERROR_NUMBER() ;
      Print ERROR_MESSAGE() ;
END CATCH
```

You can use OUTPUT with a merge. [Sample](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1325508-391-1.aspx)

Comment: thanks, but I really need to figure out how to do this with the MERGE statement.

Comment: Sample your merge statement.